Core Ultra vs Ryzen for deep learning, video editing and programming?
I'm building a PC to try something new.
The use cases:

Programming (web, mobile, big data) so it needs to handle emulators, many Docker containers, etc.
Video editing (I'm a newbie so Davinci, Premiere or some open source software)
Image editing (CaptureOne, Lightroom or another software for RAWs)
Deep learning (I'm a newbie and I want to start with NNs, LLMs, etc.)
Gaming (sometime so this is less important)

What I need:

Most of the time I will write code, read articles and watch movies so I need the PC to be silent, use low energy and keep low temperatures
For programming - fast compilation times, many Docker containers, fast emulators, fast VMs, etc.
For deep learning and data processing - not sure if learning it on home machine is a good idea but I know that AVX-512 support is crucial but maybe there are some more important factors to make system effective in AI

CPU - Core Ultra 9 285K or Ryzen 9 7950X3D?
I don't know if I need such a high-end CPU so I'm asking for your recommendations. Which CPU is minimum for my needs and which is too much for my use cases.
Intel Core Ultra

Uses less power when CPU load is low
Quick Sync Video (any comparison how it helps even in video playback?)
Performs better at JavaScript and in programs (according to some tests)
Has NPU (Neural Processing Unit) - any use for that now?
Has better built-in GPU
Is it possible to limit power usage when 100% of CPU power is not needed? Has anybody bought the new Intel CPU and what are temperatures, power management, etc. e.g. when browsing the Internet, writing code (with compilations)? How does it perform?

AMD Ryzen

Has AVX-512 support
Performs better in multi-tasking and gaming
Uses much less power at 100% CPU usage
Has its own equivalent of Quick Sync (but not sure how it performs)
Is there any way to decrease power use on 0% CPU usage? How does it perform on everyday use?

Are there any other differences for my use cases? Which would you pick?
I'm interested in the NPU if this may help somewhere when processing data, deep learning, etc.
GPU
Choice between 4070 Ti Super and 4080 Super. There are dedicated GPUs for machine learning but they are very expensive.
Cooling
I need quiet and effective cooling. Can it be achieved with air cooling system or only liquid cooling system? I'm not convinced to liquid cooling. It's probably not 100% quiet when low CPU usage and there's possibility of leaks. But maybe I'm wrong.
Max price for PC is $3000.

Ok, so first of all I'm going to guess that you mean $3000 US dollars.
$3000 is already a lot for a PC, even if it's a workstation. Energy consumption does not matter that much unless you care about that extra dollar or so every month.
I would go with Intel for the CPU just because they usually have more cores, which would definitely help with compiling code and other CPU-intensive tasks. Ryzen CPUs are better for gaming overall but as you mentioned, you aren't doing a lot of gaming either. I would go with a i7-14700K, just because an i9 is way too overkill for really any kind of coding, unless you want to play Cyberpunk 2077 at 4k lol. It already has a lot of performance, and because it is the non-F version, you can also get integrated graphics just in case you want to save power.
For the motherboard, any Z series is fine, and I would recommend getting a motherboard with a pre-installed IO shield so it makes the building process easier overall.
Cooling wise, both liquid cooling and air cooling are great, but overall the difference in reliability isn't that much anyways, and liquid cooling performs better than air cooling generally.
For memory and storage, because you mentioned that you would do programming and video editing, I would get at least 64GB of DDR5 memory and 2/3/4 terabytes of storage. One thing that a lot of people do is cheap out on their storage to bring down the cost of the computer overall, but sometimes slow and unreliable storage can be really frustrating, especially when you have a lot of important files on it.
Nvidia GPUs are great for most machine learning, but their price to performance ratio is absolute trash. I would recommend getting an AMD graphics card with more or less the same performance with a smaller price tag. I wouldn't want to cheap out on this component, as it is usually the most expensive in your PC. I would recommend getting a RX7900XT/XTX for the GPU. It's AMD's top tier card and it would last you a lot time.
Also, don't cheap out on the case. It's also something that a lot of beginner PC builders do. Cheap cases often restrict the airflow of the PC, and resulting in less performance. I would recommend getting a Corsair 4000D Airflow, it's one of the most standard cases on the market with really good performance and airflow.
Here's a list of parts that I would recommend:
i7-14700K (20 Cores)
Corsair iCUE LINK H150i LCD (You could choose the option without the LCD screen)
Asus TUF GAMING Z790-PRO WIFI ATX LGA1700 (Wifi 6E you could change to a motherboard with Wifi 7)
G.Skill Trident Z5 RGB 64 GB (2 x 32 GB) DDR5-6400 CL32 (GSkill RAM is better overall right now; Corsair RAM has had some microcontroller issues)
Samsung 990 Pro 2 TB M.2-2280 (There is a 4TB option that you could switch to)
ASRock Phantom Gaming OC Radeon RX 7900 XTX (Switch to the XT version if you want to have more budget)
Corsair 4000D Airflow
Corsair RM1000e (2023) 1000 W 80+ Gold Certified (really reliable power supply)
In total around $2200 USD. I think you have to get around 2 more extra fans to setup the airflow inside the case. I suggest that you put the radiator on the top for intake with the fan on the left, and make all of the fans on the right side on the case exhaust, so there is positive pressure in the PC, which helps with performance.
